# What are the days to avoid oiling of hair?

Tags: scripture, customs, oil

Many people say in general that on so and so day one(it applies to men/women/both) should not apply oil.

Say for example they may avoid oiling hair on full moon day(i.e., poornima) or no moon day(i.e., amavasya), Sunday, Tuesday etc.,

In case of a both women and men are there any detailed mentioning of the same? I want to know about the same with some scriptural evidence.

Comment: Sounds more like a superstition, never heard of it before!

Comment: @Just_Do_It to my knowing, I think that some among them are valid according to scriptures. Say like oiling is avoided on sundays.

Comment: Abhyanjana is generally thought of as healthy in indian sciptures. So oiling is good everyday, I suppose!

Comment: @vidyarthi [Surya ashtakam](http://hindupedia.com/en/Surya_ashtakam) mentions that oil bath is not allowed on Sundays.